# SPARQL Queries with SimpleTcProvider

Tags: jena, apache-stanbol

I'm new to Jena, Clerezza, and OSGI so hopefully you'll forgive my ignorance...  I'm trying to use Apache Stanbol to make a general enhancement engine that takes as a string parameter a SPARQL query and then works on the enhancements produced by the enhancement chain so far.  I use a JenaSparqlEngine and a SimpleTcProvider to create a TcManager which can then execute the sparql queries as strings on the metadata of the content item.  That works fine for read only queries, but when I try to use update queries I get parser exceptions.  So I'm guessing I have to use (Jena) UpdateAction to perform update operations.  Can I still use the SimpleTcProvider?  Should I use Fuseki?  If you have any examples that would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  It works with SingleTdbDatasetTcProvider.